# Extract unique string from each line containing <string>

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

Here is an example block of text from a file:

---

```
Now is the time for all blah:1; to come to the aid
Now is the time for all blah:1; to come to the aid
Now is the time for all blah:1; to come to the aid
Now is the time for all blah:10; to come to the aid
Go to your happy place  blah:100; to come to the aid
Go to your happy place  blah:4321; to come to the aid
Go to your happy place  blah:4321; to come to the aid
Now is the time for all blah:4321; to come to the aid
Now is the time for all blah:9876; to come to the aid
Now is the time for all blah:108636; to come to the aid
Now is the time for all blah:1194996; to come to the aid
```

---

Question: 
How would I extract all unique numbers from lines that have "is the" in them?

I've tried using `grep -o -P -u '(?<=blah:).*(?=;)`' but it doesn't like the semi colon

Comment: Ok a little clarification: the 'print $2' solution won't work as the text preceding "blah:" varies up to appx 30 characters and includes many special characters that get interpreted as separate fields

Comment: I need to pull out only the numbers immediately following the "blah:" string because each line has multiple numbers followed by a colon

Comment: You should put all your requirements in the question (you can edit your question)

Comment: If you're happy with one or several of the answers, upvote them.  If one is solving your issue, [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) would be the best way of saying "Thank You!" :-)

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for the `\K` directive to forget about the stuff you just matched.

```
grep -oP 'is the.*?blah:\K\d+'
```

Then `sort -u`

Comment: grumble grumble, hidden requirements, mutter, mutter

Comment: The story of every software developer...

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed`:

```
$ sed -n '/is the/s/^.*blah:\([0-9]*\);.*$/\1/p' file | sort -u
1
10
108636
1194996
4321
9876
```

The substitution replaces the contents of all lines containing the string `is the` with the number between `blah:` and `;`.  Lines not containing the string are ignored.

Comment: This works great however I ran into a problem where some lines have multiple numbers followed by a colon, so I need to pull out ONLY the numbers immediately following the "blah:" string

Comment: @blake The `sed` solution would be easiest to modify: `sed -n '/is the/s/^.*blah:\([0-9]*\);.*$/\1/p' file | sort -u`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you Kusalananda - that worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**:

```
grep "is the" file | sed 's/.*blah://;s/;.*//' | sort -u
```

**Explanation**:

1. `grep` gets all lines with "`is the`" (in any part of the line)
2. `sed` remove all before "`:`" and after "`;`" (you could use `sed -e 's/.*blah://' -e 's/;.*//'` instead for best understanding)
3. `sort` sorts lines

Comment: Thanks Egor - I should have been more clear. in some of the lines there are multiple numbers followed by a colon. I need to pull out ONLY the numbers following the "blah:" string

Comment: @blake i corrected the answer according your comments

Answer (score 0):

```
cat file | grep "is the" | awk -F':' '{print $2}'|awk -F';' '{print $1}'|sort -u
```

Comment: You can combine cat|grep|awk|awk with `gawk -F '[:;]' '/is the/ {print $2}' file`

Comment: And then you can get the unique ids by using an associative array: `gawk -F '[:;]' '/is the/ {id[$2]} END {for (i in id) print i}' file`